# Can I set Organization permissions through the Google Drive API Admin-SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

I was wondering if through the Google Drive API Admin-SDK I can set and change Organization permissions for sharing, for example disabling sharing outside the organization or completely disable share.

I checked in https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-org-units but there is no API endpoint to perform that.

Also is it possible to change the Sharing settings for the entire Drive domain? For example turning on or off sharing outside the domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for changing these settings, they must be set in the CPanel. However, you could create OrgUnits in the domain, configure the Orgs with your preferred Drive sharing settings ([assumes you have Google Apps Unlimited or EDU](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6034782?hl=en)) and [programatically move users between the OUs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user) with Directory API.